# Get url Parameter for seo friendly url in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to get parameter uniqid from url but im not be able to get it.In this case i used rules in .htaccess to make this url structure `example.com/page.php?uniqid=123` to this structure `example.com/page/id/123` for the reason of seo friendly but before i use the `.htaccess` rule i was be able to get it by URLSearchParams like :

```
let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let idresolve = urlParams.get('uniqid');
```

Now i can’t get the `123` after adding the rule in `.htaccess` for this `example.com/page/id/123` structure.How can get the `123` from url?

Comment: You can try using `$route.params.uniqid`, if you are using vue-router.

Comment: @YashMaheshwari no im not using vue-router and also vuejs is added to project by cdn link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used `window.location.pathname` for set a manual offset on url.

Example: `window.location.pathname(9)` will retrieve `123` for this url `example.com/page/id/123`